# Dropping / recreating type in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[Order]') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TYPE [dbo].[Order]
GO

CREATE TYPE [dbo].[Order] AS TABLE 
(
    [Id] INT NULL,
    [Order] INT NULL
);
```

This code doesn't drop the table. I get this error:

> The type `'dbo.Order'` already exists, or you do not have permission to create it.

How I can drop/recreate type in SQL Server?

Comment: Something is off with your code. You reference Order, but your error message apparently references tblDisplayOrder. Also, which version of SQL Server are you using? Surely there's no need for 3 version tags.

Comment: @SchmitzIT I have been updated an error

Comment: @John please see below the code has been provided in the answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any of your stored procedure may be using this table type. That's why it doesn't allow you to drop. You may be getting following error.

Msg 3732, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Cannot drop type 'tabletype' because it is being referenced by object '**storedprocedurename**'. There may be other objects that reference this type.

Msg 219, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The type 'tabletype' already exists, or you do not have permission to create it.

check that storedprocedure or function name. just comment the usage for a while and once reference is removed. you can drop and recreate the table type. after that uncomment the reference usage in stored procedure / function.

This will surely works !!

Comment: How I can remove types with references in CI. I can not comment code

Comment: Regenerate scripts drop and create of particular reference procedures. execute just drop. keep that window open so that you can create it later on.. now just execute drop and create table type query. it will drop those tables and re-create. now execute create those stored procedure / functions which were referring that table type

Comment: what if a type is using in several SP

Comment: Either generate scripts of those SPs to drop and re-create or create new type table with another name say tblorder to new type table as tblorder2 and update this to those several SPs

Answer (score 4):

Try to replace the check on Object_ID by a SELECT to INFORMATION_SCHEMA.DOMAINS (for SQL Server 2012):

```
IF EXISTS( SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.DOMAINS WHERE Domain_Name = 'Order' )
    DROP TYPE [dbo].[Order]

CREATE TYPE [dbo].[Order] AS TABLE 
(
    [Id] INT NULL,
    [Order] INT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 1):

> SQL Server 2016 and above

```
DROP TYPE IF EXISTS [Tablename];
GO

CREATE TYPE [DBO].[Tablename] AS TABLE
(Test VARCHAR(50))
GO
```

> Lower verions of SQL server

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.types WHERE is_table_type = 1 AND NAME ='Tablename')
BEGIN
    DROP TYPE [dbo].[Tablename]
END
GO

CREATE TYPE [DBO].[Tablename] AS TABLE
(Test VARCHAR(50))
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IF EXISTS(
Select 1 from sys.table_types where user_type_id = TYPE_ID(N'dbo.Order')
    )
    Begin

    DROP TYPE [dbo].[Order]

    CREATE TYPE [dbo].[Order] AS TABLE 
    (
     [Id]    INT NULL,
     [Order] INT NULL
    );

   END
```

Answer (score 0):

Commenting out all places where type exists in stored procedure can be daunting task and also uncommenting that can be error prone. One trick that I use there is to right click on type that I want to change and choose Script Create UDT type to new query window, then I just change name (for example adding 2 after type name). Then I go to stored procedure(s) where I'm using this type, change with new created type and alter them. Then I can freely change original type. After I do it I can return original type in stored procedure and drop type 2. This way us much faster and reliable.